# averaging numbers and display grouped average

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a code that prompts the user to add 4 numbers and average them out and depending if that answer is 100+, 75-100, 50-75, 50- it checks if its in between the specified number zones and shows the answer respectively in a prompt box. 
*edit* The code doesn't give anything lower than group 75-100 regardless. for example, if I enter four 20's it says that its between 75 and 100 (a+ grade) which makes no sense to me. If anyone has a idea please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Looping assignment
    </title>
</head>
```

```
<script>
    var grades = new Array()

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            grades[i] = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your grades:"))  
        }

    var total = (grades[0] + grades[1] + grades[2] + grades[3])
    var average = (total / 4)

        if ( average >= 100)
            alert("How is the average higher than 100!  A+ grade/n " + average);
        if ( average > 75 && average <99)
            alert("The average is between 75 and 100.  B grade  /n " + average);
        if ( average > 50 && average <75)
             alert("The average is between 75 and 50.  C grade /n " + average);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: to write a "AND", use `&&`. So you get `if ( average > 50 && average <75)`. For your next question please state what happens and what you were expecting.

Comment: Voting to close as "typo".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `&&` operator instead of `;`

```js
var grades = new Array()

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  grades[i] = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your grades:"));
}

var total = (grades[0] + grades[1] + grades[2] + grades[3])
var average = (total / 4)

if (average >= 100)
  alert("How is the average higher than 100!  A+ grade/n " + average);
if (average > 75 && average <=99)
  alert("The average is between 75 and 100.  B grade  /n " + average);
if (average > 50 && average <=75)
  alert("The average is between 75 and 50.  C grade /n " + average);
```

Comment: No need to answer when there's already a comment explaining the typo. Just vote to close.

Comment: I was typing answer when you added a comment. Already voted to close :)

Comment: I added that but now unless the answer is 100 it just say the answer is between 75 and 100. I think its counting everything under 100 as that answer. any way to fix that?

Comment: what inputs you provided?

Comment: 50, 50, 60, 60 were the numbers I added for example.

Comment: @Convel I'm getting expected output for this input 55

Comment: I'm getting 55 as well but the response says its between 75-100  which is why I'm confused.

Comment: I'm getting correct alert. Check the snippet once again